# Multiline TabControl Set TabPage Row

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

This is probably a dumb question but I haven't been able to easily find the answer:

I have a C# application with a multiline TabControl. How do I designate a tab to appear in a specified row? I know that the rows will change from top to bottom depending on which is selected; I don't care about that. I just want given tabs to always appear in the same row as other for organization.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to control the row at all? I'm under the impression that tab rows are only dependent on the left-right order of the tabs, and the size of the form containing the tabs.

Comment: I've got a basic work around of simply arranging the tabs in the order I want and then adding white space to either side of the tab text to push tabs to another row. This seems a little goofy to me though and thought that there might be a different way of assigning a static location and size.